# iam getting this error in my c# application cannot find column2

Tags: c#, sql, database, join, error-handling

Hello Guys am getting this error "cannot find column2" I want to join both queries in one for inserting data in database everything is perfect but I don't know why am getting this type of error and I don't know how to resolve it please help me thanks

```
Here is my code:

    string sqlCust21 = "SELECT Name,sum(CAST(ubl As int)) FROM payment WHERE dates <= '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' Group By union SELECT Name,sum(CAST(ubl As int)) FROM payment WHERE dates > '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' Group By Name";
                DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlCust21);
                DataTable dtCust21 = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlCust21);
                MessageBox.Show(dtCust21.Rows[0][2].ToString());
```

Comment: You missed column name after GROUP BY in first query

Comment: Thanks but this were not the reason well still am getting this type of error see
https://imgur.com/GgQwo76

Comment: please can you modify my code on how to solve this error Thanks

Comment: I would recommend looking into using parameters in your query, this helps prevent injection.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the column name after `GROUP BY`.

```
string sqlCust21 = "SELECT Name,sum(CAST(ubl As int)) FROM payment WHERE dates <= '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' 
Group By name  --<-- this
union SELECT Name,sum(CAST(ubl As int)) FROM payment WHERE dates > '" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "' Group By Name";
```

Comment: Your syntax error is resolved by using this solution and now you are getting another error, which is becquse of index, it means this solution resolved query error which is reported in your question

Answer (score 0):

DataRowCollections are 0 based.
Try this

```
MessageBox.Show(dtCust21.Rows[0][1].ToString());
```